# Menu wrapping - Chrome CSS Issue

Tags: css

Have a look at the following page:

http://berrisford.gumpshen.com/

The last item in the top nav menu wraps in chrome I can't pin it down can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Change the width of the last LI to 255px and you'll see what i mean.

The last item is too large :)

Comment: i agree, but for Chrome (for some reason) this is the case!

Answer (score 1):

for `ul.topnav` change `font-size:1.1em` to `font-size:1em`